# ios - Programatically retrieving App installs/active devices

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

I need to programatically retrieve the number of active device installs our iOS apps have. I've been able to do this with Android, but iTunes still eludes me.

I have been looking at Apps Reporter (reporter.jar) which I've got working by using the Access Token but i cannot seem to find the data I am looking for (# of installs for each of my Apps).

I have also downloaded and used [this solution](https://github.com/Finnb8r/itunes-connect-sales-api-php) to get reports, but it still only gives data for a particular day, week, month or year, not the number of active installs.

Interestingly, I have just noticed that I can't actually see that piece of data even on the dashboard.

Can anyone help with how I can get this data? If it IS available via App Reporter, can anyone share the command to get this data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for help with coding this or with the location of the data?

Comment: Just the location of the data that I can get hold of programatically (ideally using PHP) Thank you